# Populate HTML Table with Directory/Folder Contents

Tags: php, html, html-table, directory

In a website HTML Table, I need to have the table populate with the names of PDF files located  on a specific directory of the website.

Example:

Years on left-side of table: 2010, 2011, 2012
Months across top of table: Jan, Feb, Mar

The data records need to pull from a structured folder setup from the site's root:

html_public/uploadedfiles/files_type_a/2010/01jan
html_public/uploadedfiles/files_type_a/2010/02feb
html_public/uploadedfiles/files_type_a/2010/03mar

So, a PDF document that has been uploaded into the /01jan folder would display that PDF file's name in the appropriate cell of the HTML table.

Comment: Need more information. What kind of environment? PHP or the like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This PHP code will iterate through the directory you specify and put all of the PDF files it finds into an array called `$files`. You may need to adjust the `$dir`.

```
$dir = 'html_public/uploadedfiles/files_type_a/2010/'; //directory to pull from
$skip = array('.','..'); //a few directories to ignore

$dp = opendir($dir); //open a connection to the directory
$files = array();

if ($dp) {
    while ($file = readdir($dp)) {
        if (in_array($file, $skip)) continue;

        if (is_dir("$dir$file")) {
            $innerdp = opendir("$dir$file");

            if ($innerdp) {
                while ($innerfile = readdir($innerdp)) {
                    if (in_array($innerfile, $skip)) continue;

                    $arr = explode('.', $innerfile);
                    if (strtolower($arr[count($arr) - 1]) == 'pdf') {
                        $files[$file][] = $innerfile;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This part will make an HTML table and display all of the applicable files:

```
<table>
    <? foreach ($files as $directory => $inner_files) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td>Folder: <?= $directory ?></td>
    </tr>

        <? foreach ($inner_files as $file) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>File: <?= $directory ?>/<?= $file ?></td>
        </tr>
        <? } ?>
    <? } ?>
</table>
```